# Switching a live App Store app from Universal to arm7 only

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store, universal-binary

Let's say I have an application in the App Store that has been approved and has been available for sale for some amount of time. The application is a universal (arm6+arm7) binary. Now I want to release a new version, but drop support for arm6 platforms (which was never intended as a target in the first place).

I heard that Apple will simply reject the binary if I attempt to do this. Is this true? And if so, is there any way around this whatsoever?

Comment: NB:`Universal` when refering to iOS means it runs on both iPhone/iPod and iPad, it's nothing to do with the architecture.

I don't know why Apple would reject your app for attempting to evolve it. If you've included new features, it's more that possible it just won't work on armv6 anymore. I don't know for certain, but I'd consider my comment a 'vote' for 'No, they won't reject it'

Comment: I am just using the terminology Unity3D exposes to me -- it gives me a choice between "armv6", "armv7", and "Universal armv6+armv7". It certainly resembles the traditional meaning of a universal binary, i.e. one with two or more architecture slices in the same binary.

Comment: Try this and report your results back.  I'm very curious.